# Xero API Integration with no user interface (machine-2-machine)

Tags: php, laravel, xero-api

I am trying to integrate Xero API to post invoice from my web application (internal operation). According to latest API articles, there is only way to integrate it using "machine to machine" solution which is described here https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/machine-2-machine
Is there anyone have done it before? Please help me on this regards. Thanks!

Comment: Have you watched this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcf_64yreVI&t=3s ) ? That's given me enough to get my code working - I had a Windows Service working with OAuth1 which I was struggling to see how to convert to OAuth2 because of the need to manually sign in. I hadn't seen that page before, I don't notice new stuff that appears on the developer site and I don't see any way to get notifications for it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sure it'll help a lot.